# Strong lower semicontinuity theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, semicontinuous-functions

In the book Dacorogna - "Direct methods in the calculus of variations", corollary 3.22 on page 94 states:

Let $p \geq 1$, $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ open and $f:\Omega \times \mathbb R^{N \times n} \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function satisfying

$$f(x,\xi) \geq \langle a(x), \xi \rangle + b(x)$$

for some $a \in L^{p'}$, $1/p+1/p'=1$, $b \in L^1$. Let

$$I(u)=\int_\Omega f(x, \nabla u(x)) dx.$$

Then $I(u)$ is lower semicontinuous.

Proof: define $g(x,\xi)=f(x,\xi)-\langle a(x), \xi \rangle + b(x)$. If $$G(u)=\int_\Omega g(x, \nabla u(x)) dx$$ is lsc then $$I(u)=\int_\Omega f(x, \nabla u(x)) dx$$ is also lsc, hence we can assume $f \geq 0$ without loss of generality.

Let us take $\xi_\nu \overset{L^p}{\to}\xi$. There exist a subsequence which converges almost everywhere $\xi_{\nu_k}(x) \to \xi(x)$ hence we can use Fatou's lemma

$$\liminf_{\nu_k} \int_\Omega f(x,\xi_{\nu_k}(x))dx \geq \int_\Omega \liminf_{\nu_k} f(x,\xi_{\nu_k}(x))dx$$
and the proof ends with the statement "Combining the above inequality with the lower semicontinuity of f, we have the claim."

My question is: isn't the inequality only valid for a particular subsequence? How do you conclude that it is valid also for $\xi_\nu$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term
\begin{align*}
\liminf_{\nu}\int_{\Omega}f(x,\xi_{\nu}(x))dx
\end{align*}
can be realized to a subsequence
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\nu_{k}}\int_{\Omega}f(x,\xi_{\nu_{k}}(x))dx.
\end{align*}
Meanwhile the subsequence $\{\xi_{\nu_{k}}\}$ has a further subsequence $\{\xi_{v_{k_{l}}}\}$ such that $\xi_{\nu_{k_{l}}}(x)\rightarrow\xi(x)$ a.e.

Following the reasoning in the reference, we get
\begin{align*}
\liminf_{\nu_{k_{l}}}\int_{\Omega}f(x,\xi_{\nu_{k_{l}}}(x))dx\geq I(\xi).
\end{align*}
But then
\begin{align*}
\liminf_{\nu_{k_{l}}}\int_{\Omega}f(x,\xi_{\nu_{k_{l}}}(x))dx=\lim_{\nu_{k}}\int_{\Omega}f(x,\xi_{\nu_{k}}(x))dx
\end{align*}
since the former sequence is a subsequence of the later convergent sequence.